# How do I get started with SQL databases in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am going to use C# to access a SQL database, initializing a connection and create tables and editing stuff, so is SQL Server required to start using SQL queries in C# ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're going to issue SQL queries you need *some* sort of SQL implementation. It doesn't have to be SQL Server though... is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Sql Server Express is freely available (in fact you may already have it depending on your Visual Studio), just in case you need a server.

Comment: **queries** (as plural of **query**) - *quarries* are where stone like marble etc. is being cut ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

SqlClient (System.Data.SqlClient) is included as part of .NET framework, but you'd be wise to get a connection to an SQL server at some stage so that you can test your connection code.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to just about any SQL database using C# and .NET.

Microsoft's tooling works best with Microsoft SQL server, so if you want to experiment with SQL access in .NET, set up Microsoft SQL server on your development machine.

I suggest you try the free [Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) (use the "Download ... with tools" link).